# How to have powershell go through a list of users and if they exists move them to ou mentioned if not display the username with failed.

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ou

Okay so i have the following code. It works but it returns failed for each user. The first 2 users are supposed to fail but the last one should be success but it should only show all the failed attempts and then place it in a text file. This is what I have so far besides the output to a text file.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#$sam = read-host "Enter username"
#$user = Get-ADUser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $sam}

$user = @("user2","user3","olduser2")
foreach($sam in $user){
if(Get-Aduser $sam){
$Name = (Get-ADUser $sam -Properties cn).name
$path = "OU=Term,OU=test,DC=patel,DC=COM"
Get-ADUser $Name | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $path
}
if(!$sam){
Write-Host "$sam failed"
}
```

It would return 
user2 failed
with a an error message because it cant be found

user3 failed
with a an error message because it cant be found

olduser2 failed 
without error message.

Answer (score 1):

The iterator variable (`$sam`) in the `ForEach` goes out of scope when the `ForEach` loop exits. At that point, `$sam -eq $null` is true (equivalent to `!$sam`), and therefore you will get the failure message. Try

```
$user = @("user2","user3","olduser2")
foreach($sam in $user){
    if(Get-Aduser $sam){
        $Name = (Get-ADUser $sam -Properties cn).name
        $path = "OU=Term,OU=test,DC=patel,DC=COM"
        Get-ADUser $Name | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $path
    } else {
        Write-Host "$sam failed"
    }
}
```

and see if that gives you the results you want - and if you can understand *why* it does. There are other improvements you can make in the script, as well - but you should get it working first, then think about optimization.

Comment: So it still gives me the errors but it works for olduser2 but it doesnt display user2 failed user3 failed

Comment: It says cannot find object with identity 'user 2' how do i get it display only that user2 failed and so on for all of them

Comment: Please paste the _exact_ and _entire_ text of the error message you are getting. Usually, the error message tells you which command is failing.

Comment: Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: User 2' under: 'DC=Patel
,DC=COM'.
At C:\Users\shpate\Desktop\Scripts\disabled_ou_move.ps1:10 char:11
+ Get-ADUser <<<<  $Name | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $path
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (User 2:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'User 2' under: 'DC=patel,DC=COM'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: it then says that all three user2, user3, and olduser2 failed. It supposed to only say user2 and user3 failed so i can go back and change the ou manually

Comment: You need to rethink your error checking and logic - obviously, `Get-ADUser` throws a terminating error if it can't find the user you're looking for. At the point that the error is being thrown, you have clearly entered the 'then' section of the `if` construct; that's where I'd look for your problem.

 - You should also use parameter names, and not rely on positional parameters or aliases. Doing so makes your code clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Remove the first `Get-ADUser` in the `if` block. Change the second to `Get-ADUser $sam | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $path`

Comment: @BenH - I was hoping the querent would do his own troubleshooting and arrive at that conclusion. That's a logic error that he should have caught almost immediately. Using the full parameter names, and reading up on the usage thereof, probably would have let him catch it.

Comment: @ShivPatel `Get-ADUser` doesn't take `Name` as an `-Identity` which was the issue

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff Zeitlin mentioned in the comments of the answer. This would be better to do error checking in a `try` `catch` loop.

```
$user = @("user2","user3","olduser2")
foreach($sam in $user) {
    try {
        $path = "OU=Term,OU=test,DC=patel,DC=COM"
        Get-ADUser $sam -ErrorAction Stop | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $path -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "$sam failed"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. This is a much better structure. But I tend to teach fishing, not hand out fish. :)

Comment: @ShivPatel If an answer worked for you, it is best practice to accept it.